# Preselect configurable product options by simple product URL

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

How to show configurable product with preselected options if requested url is for simple product?

***For example:***

*Simple product #1* has:
**Color:** `Red`
**URL:** `/simple-red.html`

*Simple product #2* has:
**Color:** `Green`
**URL:** `/simple-green.html`

*Configurable product* has:
**URL:** `/config.html`

If user visits `/simple-red.html` it should be loaded *configurable product* with pre-selected option **Color:** `Red`

If user visits `/simple-green.html` it should be loaded *configurable product* with pre-selected option **Color:** `Green`

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: @RaviChomal Updated question by adding an example

Comment: \js\varien\configurable.js in this file in line number:303 you will change here for do this functionlity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successfully solved the problem:

1. Extended `ProductController`, to replace product id of simple product by product id of parent configurable product. Used SO Answer:
   [Magento Catalog ProductController rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738934/3106547)
   Code in custom `ProductController`:

   ```
   ...
   $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

   // Get parent configurable product
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
   if ($_product->getTypeId() == "simple") {
       $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());

       // If parent exists
       if (isset($parentIds[0])) {
           $productId = $parentIds[0];
       }
   }
   ...
   ```
2. PreSelect configurable product options depending on simple product. Used [link to tutorial given by Vishal Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23607355/3106547)

**Result** (sorry can't post images):
[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55521820/shared/so-magento-simple-product-url.PNG)

Comment: Where is the link to the tutorial?  The link you provided didn't do anything.