# Preselect configurable product options based on simple product

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, configurable-product

This is a very similar question to this:
[Preselect configurable product options by simple product URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607051/preselect-configurable-product-options-by-simple-product-url/)
But the important part of the answer just points to a dead link.

There are a million pages that explain how to get the configurable product from the simple product, but not the configurable product with the options set to what would produce the simple product.

I need this for a couple areas.  First, there's a section of the site that will programatically add the product to the cart based on SKU.  It finds the simple product via SKU, and I can get its parent product, but I can't add that to the cart with the options that will point it to the simple product.

Secondly, I need the link that's generated for the simple product to show the page for it's configurable product, with the appropriate options selected since we're generating links for an external service that gets the links to all the simple product pages which are currently disabled.

I've looked everywhere but can't find how to get the configurable product options selected.

Comment: have you tried looking at `app/design/frontend/.../template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`? That's where the dropdown is built.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is determining which option needs to be selected based on the simple product.